# Regex repeat patterns and non matching groups

Tags: c++, regex

Okay so I am having an issue getting a repeat to work at all, let alone the way I want it to work...

I will be bringing in a string with the following information

```
NETWORK;PASS;1;THIS TEXT|CAN BE|RANDOM|WITH|PIPE|SEPERATORS;\r
```

what I have so far

```
(?:NETWORK;.*;(?:0|1);)([^|]*)
```

this currently leaves me the first block matched

```
THIS TEXT
```

what I am trying to do is set it up so I can programmatically specify which block to match. the text separated with pipes will have between 3-7 "blocks" and depending on the situation I may need to match any one of them, but only one at a time.

I had thought about just duplicating

```
([^|]*)
```

and adding a non matching operator to all but the one but I cant seem to get it to match anything if I duplicate that group, and neither can I get repeat operators to work on the group.

I am a bit lost so this may not make entire sense if clarification is required I will provide on request. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Either this relates to C++ regular expressions (boost or standard library), some C library for regular expressions, or regular expressions in general (and ditch the C and C++ tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just split `THIS TEXT|CAN BE|RANDOM|WITH|PIPE|SEPERATORS` on the pipe symbol? Much easier than a dynamically-generated regex.

But if you really want to generate a regex:

1. Start with `(?:NETWORK;.*;(?:0|1);)`
2. To get the nth element (indexed from 0), add `(?:[^|]+[|]){n}` (replace `n` with the number to skip), followed by `([^|]+)`

Example:

```
(?:NETWORK;.*;(?:0|1);)(?:[^|]+[|]){3}([^|]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RoWJT8tHiSzIoYnz)

Matches `WITH` in your example. [**Here's a regex101 demo.**](http://regex101.com/r/uO0aH5)

Comment: This is pretty much everything I was looking for, I was testing with regex101 however it just doesn't match anything return a match on that site, is there a particular site you use

Comment: I use https://www.debuggex.com/.  [My example is working on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uO0aH5), though. The issue with your first attempt was in duplicating `([^|]*)` - there's no allowance for the `|`, which you also need to take into account with each repeat.